# Add data to csv column based on row value

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV that I read in. The problem is that this CSV as columns that are not filled with data. I need to go through a column and when the ID number matches the ID of the content I want to add, add in the data. Currently I have,

```
$counter = 0
foreach($invoice in $allInvoices){
  $knownName += $info | where-Object{$_.'DOCNUMBR'.trim().contains($cleanInvNum)}
  $DocNumbr = $info | where-Object{$_.'DOCNUMBR'.trim() -eq $cleanInvNum}
  $output = $ResultsTable.Rows.Add(" ", " ", " ", " ", $DocNumbr[$counter].'ORG', $DocNumbr[$counter].'CURNT', $knownName[$counter].'DOCNUMBR', " ")
  $counter++
}
```

The problem with this code is that it just adds rows under the CSV and does not add the data to the row. How can I do a statement where I find ID and add the above content into that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by reworking my foreach loop and setting the values directly like so,

```
$output.'CheckNumber' = $DocNumbr.'ORTRXAMT'
$output.'CheckDate' = $DocNumbr.'CURTRXAM'
$output.'Invoice Number' = $knownName.'DOCNUMBR'
```